# Is there a way to get a list of recently clocked tasks from the org-mode clock, on the command line?

Tags: org-mode, org-clock

I'm trying to make a little script that will allow me to list and clock in on recent tasks from the command line, so that I can put it into an Argos script and have it be basically have it be an org clock GNOME shell extension. I noticed that there's the variable org-clock-history which is a list of markers. And I'm guessing markers are character offsets? So I might be able to translate those markers into headings, and so forth. But there must be an easier way, I'm guessing.

So, is there a way to get a list of recently clocked tasks (i.e., headings) from the org-mode clock? I've discovered that I can run `emacsclient --eval '(elisp here)'` to run elisp. Now all I have to do is figure out what to put in there.

Comment: See the chapter on markers in the Emacs Lisp manual and  more particularly the section on [information from Markers](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Information-from-Markers.html#Information-from-Markers) in that chapter.

Comment: What should I be looking for there? I don't see anything relevant

Comment: `org-clock-history` is a list of *markers*. For each of those markers you can get the relevant buffer and the position in the buffer using the functions on that page.

Comment: Ok, but then you have the position in the buffer, and the buffer, but how does that help me to get a list of clocked tasks from the command line?